# Do reopened questions get moved back to the top of the stack of recent questions?

Tags: support, bump, vote-to-reopen

If a question is placed on-hold, the post is edited to become a better question, and then the question gets reopened, does it remain in the **Newest** questions list in the same spot it was when it was originally posted or does it move up to become the most current question?

Specifically, I'm curious about the electronics.stackexchange.com website. Is this the same across all exchange websites?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped

Comment: @gnat I should have clarified what I meant by "recent questions". I mean what pops up on the **Newest** tab. Also I think this question may need to be moved to the meta.stackexchange website as I actually was interested in this due to the electronics.stackexchange.com website. I'll edit my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reopened questions don't show up on "newest" since they aren't actually new. That view is sorted in reverse chronological order by  the date and time when questions were originally asked.

Reopening a question "bumps" it up to the top of the "active" view, though, which on all sites except Stack Overflow also happens to be the default homepage view.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions
Takes me straight to the **Newest** tab as the default so I'm not sure your second statement is correct.

Comment: @horta That's not the homepage. http://electronics.stackexchange.com is.

Comment: @horta It doesn't necessarily take you to "newest", it takes you to whichever tab you last used.  It will remember which tab that was.  You last used the newest tab, so that's where you were sent.

Comment: @AnnaLear gotcha, you're right. I wasn't sure if there was some history. Thank you also for clarifying the difference between the homepage and the questions area. I've been on here awhile and that's the first time I've noticed the difference.

Comment: @horta Any time :)