# The question thread shows a post as being modified but on the question page there is no visible modification

Tags: feature-request

I was going over the questions thread this morning on meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and noticed that a post was shown as being modified.

But when I visited that post, I found no evidence of anything being modified, be it the question or any of the answers given.

The post in question:

- [Is a question that asks how to do something which would require a tutorial in an answer too broad or off topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295849/is-a-question-that-asks-how-to-do-something-which-would-require-a-tutorial-in-an)

I also included a screenshot. Is this a bug?

[image]

## Edit:

Pulled from a comment by [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene):

> [it takes the events that are recorded in the PostHistory table. there are 30+ of such events. Do you suggest we find the correct verb for all of them? Personally I think modified is fine. I can deal with the rare cases it means something different. – rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358915/the-thread-showed-a-post-as-being-modified-but-i-failed-to-see-any-evidence#comment529273_358915)

Sure, "modified" is fine and I wasn't asking to create a new message for it.

So now my question would be:

- why wouldn't it also have been shown in the question as being modified for the date/time it was reopened, and where it presently shows as [edited Jun 2 '15 at 16:32](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/295849/revisions)? (See the new screenshot).
- I feel it's **misleading**, so why even show it in the question's thread as being modified and not including it in the post itself that it was modified in any way? **This including a post being reopened.**

**At first glance and taken as "face value",** that doesn't say/show anything in regards to the question's thread showing it was modified.

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/295849/revisions those nasty Gold Badge holders re-open questions without *almost* leaving a trace ...

Comment: The post was reopened.

Comment: @rene errr. ok thanks :)) but why did it show as being modified in the thread? Rather than saying "modified 14 hours ago", shouldn't it have shown "post reopened 14 hours ago"?

Comment: @MartijnPieters see my above ^ maybe I should edit my post.

Comment: it takes the events that are recorded in the PostHistory table. there are 30+ of such events. Do you suggest we find the correct verb for all of them? Personally I think *modified* is fine. I can deal with the rare cases it means something different.

Comment: @rene No, I don't suggest to change the wording for it. I've edited my post in light of your comment.

Comment: I'd really like my post to be taken seriously. There is something obviously wrong here but many fail to see it. That's kind of a pun in itself.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258072/do-reopened-questions-get-moved-back-to-the-top-of-the-stack-of-recent-questions

Comment: @yivi I'm aware of that already, that isn't what my question is about. Please read it over again and in its entirety; most importantly the edit that was made.

Comment: Technically you are correct. Which is the best kind of correct.

Answer (score 3):

Ironically, as the person that triggered this, I actually *don't* disagree with what you're saying here.

All post events are captured, and are displayed as a modification to the post.  In the most technical of senses, a binding reopen vote does modify the post, but it doesn't really *modify* the post.  There's nothing to suggest that I edited the post or anything like that; just that it was reopened.

I feel like it'd be more convenient to show binding reopens as "reopened by" instead of "modified by", since that's usually a detail that's overlooked (and not many people know how to find [the timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/295849/timeline#history_c25433eb-ed1e-4962-b3c6-d8594fbdaddd)).

Comment: *"it'd be more convenient to show binding reopens as "reopened by" instead of "modified by", since that's usually a detail that's overlooked"* - Agreed and it'd be nice that something be done about it. --- *"(and not many people know how to find the timeline)."* - You're right and I for one am not quite knowledgeable about those, so we need to take into account the "total" newbies to meta and how it all works. Things are taken as "face value" and they should, no exceptions.

Comment: But @Fred, you said that the "modified" message was OK, and that was not the part you wanted to change, and Makoto is proposing exactly that (as I also said a minute ago)

Comment: @yivi In a comment to rene, yes. But as this goes, my comment should have been something else and I apologize (to everyone) for that comment. The question really revolves around the fact that the "face value" for the post in question did not show it as being modified, only in the question thread. That's what this all boils down to. Imagine if you saw something for sale and on special on a website or a flyer that didn't state the item is no longer "on sale" or the price changed, but didn't reflect it in there and just in the store? ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, you say it in your question, not in a comment ("_Sure, "modified" is fine and I wasn't asking to create a new message for it_"). Still, if it's good for you, happiness all around. I still think if there is something to fix, is the part you didn't want to address, but that is not particularly important.

Comment: @yivi Yeah, I see the confusion that that triggered. Let me see what I can do about that.

Comment: @yivi Ok fair enough. I'll just leave well enough alone ;-)

Answer (score -4):

I don't see much to fix here. Open questions do not shows a special status message, since they already are on their *default* state.

A re-opened question is just an open question that used to be closed. That it was recently closed is no longer relevant.

You logically **need** the status message when the question is closed (to tell you why you can't answer it), but it is not needed nor pertinent when it is open. You can judge the question on its current state, despite it being closed in the past.

You say: "*At first glance and taken as "face value", that doesn't say/show anything in regards to the question's thread showing it was modified*". But the question wasn't *modified*, it was *re-opened*. And that the question **used** to be closed is not important to consider the question. As of now, the question is **open**.

Regardless, bumping the question to the top of active list **makes sense**: the question was closed for answers, but now is open for business again so it may benefit from some additional attention/exposure. People who couldn't answer before (because it was closed) can answer it now.

I know that you say that adding a new "verb" for the thread ("reopened" instead of "modified") is not what you want, but for me that would be better than showing that a question was re-opened recently (although not extremely useful on itself).

Better still, leave things as they are. IMO, this is neither a bug nor needed new feature.

Comment: See Makoto's answer, which makes more sense to me and has come the closest to being an answer for all this. Them being the person who reopened the question "in question".

Comment: Yup, I saw. Glad it helps you! That Makoto was the one reopening the question is hardly relevant anyway. And what he proposes is what you say you don't want. But still, if it's good for you, great!

Comment: *"no bug here"* - It's hard to say if it's a bug or not and the "bug tag" was removed in an edit earlier by someone else. I'll just leave the question as it is and see if anything else comes of it.